# Is it necessary to return a Promise function?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

Is it necessary to return a Promise function if I'm using await & async in Node 8+?

```
async function _readSourceDataFromCache (slug_name) {
    aerospikeClient = aerospikeConf.AerospikeClient;
    console.log('In async function')
    console.log(aerospikeClient);
    return new Promise ( function (resolve, reject) {
        aerospikeClient.get(aerospikeConf.AerospikeKey, function (error, record) {
            if (error) {
              switch (error.code) {
                case aerospikeConf.Aerospike.status.AEROSPIKE_ERR_RECORD_NOT_FOUND:
                  console.log('NOT_FOUND -', aerospikeConf.AerospikeKey)
                  break
                default:
                  console.log('ERR - ', error, aerospikeConf.AerospikeKey)
              }
              resolve(false)
            }
            else{
                resp = record['value']
                aerospikeClient.close();
                return resolve(resp);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

How do I handle this from the calling function?

Comment: Do I need to use a try/catch block from the calling function?

Comment: Although `async` functions naturally return Promises already, it looks like you need to construct a `Promise` explicitly in order to transform the `aerospikeClient.get` call to a Promise rather than a callback.

Comment: IMHO this is too short to be an answer but you handle it like this: `_readSourceDataFromCache(something).then(callback_function)`

Answer (score 1):

You should return your `promise` (I think you can use that `promise` to use something)

But `async` is not necessary.

`async` mark you should wait `promise` resolved with `await`

```
async yourFunction(){
    console.log('Something');
    await readDataBase(); // wait this promise return it's result
    console.log('Oh, done!!!')
}
```

Your function return a `Promise`, and don't wait it done.
If you want wait it, please use `async` for functionParent (this function call your function).